# CASSANDRA 3.16: Invalid yaml file error with well-formed yaml

Tags: java, cassandra, yaml

I'm trying to setup a 3.16 version of cassandra. At startup, I've got this message:

```
ERROR [main] 2020-05-26 11:58:42,970 CassandraDaemon.java:774 - Exception encountered during startup: Invalid yaml: file:/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml
 Error: null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=prepared_statements_cache_size_mb for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@5427c60c; For input string: "auto";  in 'reader', line 3, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'thehivedb'
```

I've checked up my yaml file with a tool and it says ok.
I've added prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: 'auto' to my config file but it continues to fail with the same error message.

Can anyone helps me?
Thanks 
Matthieu

cassandra.yaml

```
---

cluster_name: 'thehivedb'

######## debug ########
# valeurs requises non specifiees comme telles

prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: 'auto'

########

num_tokens: 256

hinted_handoff_enabled: true

max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours

hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024

max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

hints_directory: /data/elasticsearch/cassandra/hints

hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000

max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128

batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024

# - AllowAllAuthenticator performs no checks - set it to disable authentication.
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

# - AllowAllAuthorizer allows any action to any user - set it to disable authorization.
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

role_manager: CassandraRoleManager

roles_validity_in_ms: 2000

permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000

credentials_validity_in_ms: 2000

partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:
    - /data/elasticsearch/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /data/elasticsearch/cassandra/commitlog

cdc_enabled: false

disk_failure_policy: stop

commit_failure_policy: stop

prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: auto

thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: auto

key_cache_size_in_mb:

key_cache_save_period: 14400

row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

row_cache_save_period: 0

counter_cache_size_in_mb:

counter_cache_save_period: 7200

saved_caches_directory: /data/elasticsearch/cassandra/saved_caches

commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"

concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32

concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32

memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers

index_summary_capacity_in_mb:

index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60

trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

listen_interface: eth0

start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042

start_rpc: false

rpc_address: localhost

rpc_port: 9160

rpc_keepalive: true

rpc_server_type: sync

thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

incremental_backups: false

snapshot_before_compaction: false

auto_snapshot: true

column_index_size_in_kb: 64

column_index_cache_size_in_kb: 2

range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 500

cross_node_timeout: false

endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra

client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra

internode_compression: dc

inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false

tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800

enable_user_defined_functions: false

enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false

windows_timer_interval: 1

transparent_data_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    chunk_length_kb: 64
    cipher: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    key_alias: testing:1
    key_provider:
      - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.security.JKSKeyProvider
        parameters:
          - keystore: conf/.keystore
            keystore_password: cassandra
            store_type: JCEKS
            key_password: cassandra

tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000

batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5

batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50

unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10

compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100

gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000

back_pressure_enabled: false
back_pressure_strategy:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure
      parameters:
        - high_ratio: 0.90
          factor: 5
          flow: FAST

enable_materialized_views: true

enable_sasi_indexes: true
```

Answer (score 1):

So first, well-formedness and validity are two separate things. A YAML document is well-formed when a YAML parser can read it without error. However, it is only valid if the contained structure matches the target data structure. Checking a document for well-formedness therefore does not guarantee that it is valid.

Let's look at the [target data structure](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/3.11.6/org/apache/cassandra/config/Config.html):

```
java.lang.Long        prepared_statements_cache_size_mb
```

This setting is declared to be of type `Long`. `'auto'` cannot be parsed as `Long`, hence the error. You must either enter a `Long` number or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in flyx's answer, this:

```
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb: 'auto'
```

is not valid.  If you don't want to set it to a specific value, then either comment-out the line all together, or return it to its original state:

```
prepared_statements_cache_size_mb:
```

Come to think of it, the description in the yaml itself probably led to this problem:

```
# Default value ("auto") is 1/256th of the heap or 10MB, whichever is greater
```

Now, *why* that also reports as an issue with `cluster_name` is another problem all together.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. I'm not used to set empty parameters and did not understood the comments completly. Once parameters set to empty values, it works! Thanks for help :)